# How to create a Mapped Type in TypeScript with variable generic arguments?

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object containing one or more `PreparedStatement`. I need to generalize the type definition for such object. Is it possible to represent that?

```
type PreparedQuery<Input, Result> = {
  input: Input;
  result: Result;
};

type Query = {
  [Key in string]: PreparedQuery<Input, Result>;
};
```

Each value of the `Query` type of object would be `PreparedQuery` but with different `Input` and/or `Result`. The main goal is to write a function that will take a this object and return a new object that will have the type (`Query` -> `GeneratedQueries`):

```
type GeneratedQueries = {
  [Key in string]: <Input, Result>(input: Input) => Promise<Result>;
}
```

So, how do define/represent this `Query` type than can have any type of for its generic arguments?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Woa08N) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
type GeneratedQueries<Q extends { [K in keyof Q]: PreparedQuery<any, any> }> =
    { [K in keyof Q]: (input: Q[K]['input']) => Promise<Q[K]['result']> }
```

The idea is that we allow the type parameter `Q` to be an object type with any property keys whatsoever, and where each property value is of type `PreparedQuery<any, any>`.  We don't really want to constrain the input and output types to that `PreparedQuery`, so we use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) as the type arguments.

Then we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `Q` to produce the functions you want.  For each key `K` in `keyof Q`, we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the corresponding `PreparedQuery` property `Q[K]` to get the `'input` and `'result` types.

Let's test it:

```
interface Foo {
    a: { input: string, result: number },
    b: { input: Date, result: boolean },
    c: { input: HTMLElement, result: string }
}

type GeneratedQueriesForFoo = GeneratedQueries<Foo>
/* type GeneratedQueriesForFoo = {
    a: (input: string) => Promise<number>;
    b: (input: Date) => Promise<boolean>;
    c: (input: HTMLElement) => Promise<string>;
} */
```

Looks good!  Note that we could also have used [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types):

```
type GeneratedQueries<Q extends { [K in keyof Q]: PreparedQuery<any, any> }> =
    { [K in keyof Q]: Q[K] extends PreparedQuery<infer I, infer R> ?
        (input: I) => Promise<R> : never }
```

which gives the same result.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThMBDBATAigVwnEAeASQDsxNgAaKAJQgGdMAbYAPigF4oBvAKCj6gCWJMgC4oxUsADcvfgnpMxNBdO4BfGdyJIAtnWQBjaABkA9qYDWmMF26y+oSFADiEIjiTAIGbHAF08dCgIAA8vIlRaLigAbQBpQSIoCwgQUwAzKHQAXTF4RBRvLBx8JCIQSjKQVjVWNnt+Pk5YhKFk1Iys3KgACiFJMXR47JiAcn6yUeyASnZWeFMdAVoIQOGx+UZgKZq7RqEvOHSkIygAMXNbRsakMWaJ4DFaYD8iAHNKTcUoIkwdACMcFA1OQGo1-ndEgMoAARTwQT50LZif7mBgQMrA0HXfgGSEPMQACQAKgBZYwAUXReiIFCgX0eUGerzewIaaj2-Ec0Fc7jg8J8OH8tAucAupnYLjcHi8gr8AXFzAaAHoAFRQblSvkC4rykWmMWXDg8HF8W69AlMl5CN6zNjzOCLZarX4AnDMGSmqAQi3CRlwrx2h1OlZ4VGmdFlD1g3FiPp+olkynUtzAIOwR1LUPMm3RxpqKCq5V2DlaXT6E7QYjpIE8Bqa3kyoq+YWBYJhNyRaLxRLtNKZHJ5BDINC60rlSrlGp1GNNFq9lL9rqDYbt8Jd-Ij5slPBCGtwcSUPdAqisAD8s+u8ehBHTCyzq1PUDE7gAbkDS-taThjqdxVdTXNe4EytFlERUF8-kBA8QUvH1gOhAMEXpJFvnDSMklgr08WiS0SXJKkIBpOkGSea13jZfNOQccAeWlflZV1YVRX-DhGwY7c9TwRUVXVBt6J1Fs6BYo0AJxc1r1EUCbTvTNnTwV1oLzU0fUk-14VkkNVnQjEiGUnEcLUxMCJTWlNIfPAc3efTgULYs1CAA)